# TemplateDoesNotExist at /board/boards

Tags: python, django, templates

I got this error during the python django project
I do not understand why the template does not connect.
Please let me know which part of the error it is and let me know how to fix it.

How can I to do?
Attach an error picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CHfL.png)

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    --- skip ---
    board.apps.BoardConfig',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

These are my project sub-lists

```
/mysite
    /board
        /migrations
        /templates
            /board
                board_list.html
                board_detail.html
                search.html
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    /mysite
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
    /static
        css
        js
        image
    /templates
        base.html
        main.html
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

/mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import MainHome

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', MainHome.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^board/', include('board.urls', namespace='board'),
]
```

/mysite/board/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *
from mysite.views import MainHome

app_name = 'board_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MainHome.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^search/$', SearchFormView.as_view(), name='search'),
    url(r'^boards/$', BoardList.as_view(), name='board_list'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BoardDetail.as_view(), name='board_detail'),
]
```

/mysite/borad/views

```
from .models import Board
from django.views.generic import ListView
--- skip ---

class BoardList(ListView):
    model = Board
    template_name = 'board_list.html'
    content_object_name = 'boards'
    paginate_by = 10

--- skip ---
```

Comment: Look for the place where a template path with `/board/boards/` is constructed. Fix that, because your templates are in `/board/`, not in a subdirectory there.

Comment: @RolandWeber there not made dir 'boards'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/mysite/borad/views`, you have:

```
template_name = 'board_list.html'
```

Replace it with:

```
template_name = 'board/board_list.html'
```

Because `board_list.html` is inside `templates/board`.

### Edit

In `settings.py`, you have:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

which means that Django will look for templates in your `mysite/templates` folder. Remove it like this:

```
'DIRS': []
```

so Django will look by default inside `templates/` directory for every installed app.

Comment: @Mux did you add board to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yeah, INSTALLED_APPS [ -- skip -- 'board.apps.BoardConfig',]

Comment: @Mux Also try to change the name of `templates` folder inside `mysite` directory. It might be the reason. Don't forget to change any references to it as well.

Comment: For `INSTALLED_APPS`, why are you using `board.apps.BoardConfig` not just `board`?

Comment: 'board.apps.BoardConfig' same 'board'

Comment: OK. Remeber that you need to change any reference to `board_list.html` to `board/board_list.html` inside your files

Answer (score 0):

Your template is inside board directory. And your model template name is not referencing to that path.

In your `class BoardList` add `template_name = 'board/board_list.html'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a systematic approach:

- in settings.py, define **`TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')`**
- Given your directory structure, your app name is **board** not **board_app**. So, set INSTALLED_APPS = [..., **'board'**]. Also, I don't understand in your code why you refered to `board.apps.BoardConfig` instead of `board`, maybe am I missing something
- TEMPLATES = [{ .... **'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR]**, ... }] will make things more visible
- in urls.py of board app, set **`app_name=board`**
- in views.py, if you use Django naming conventions for file / directories, you don't need to specify the template name for class based views. Remove `template_name = 'board_list.html` provided your template is in `board/templates/board/board_list.html`

Also, reboot the server after performing those changes.
Does this help?

Comment: Oh, I will try.